# How to Check Version of Ping?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ping, version

I have tried to check ping's version on my Ubuntu machine using:

```
ping -version
```

but it gives me this:

```
ping: invalid option -- 'e'
Usage: ping [-aAbBdDfhLnOqrRUvV64] [-c count] [-i interval] [-I interface]
            [-m mark] [-M pmtudisc_option] [-l preload] [-p pattern] [-Q tos]
            [-s packetsize] [-S sndbuf] [-t ttl] [-T timestamp_option]
            [-w deadline] [-W timeout] [hop1 ...] destination
Usage: ping -6 [-aAbBdDfhLnOqrRUvV] [-c count] [-i interval] [-I interface]
             [-l preload] [-m mark] [-M pmtudisc_option]
             [-N nodeinfo_option] [-p pattern] [-Q tclass] [-s packetsize]
             [-S sndbuf] [-t ttl] [-T timestamp_option] [-w deadline]
             [-W timeout] destination
```

However, I get the version if i try it with fping.

Comment: As you are obviusly a newbe in the linuxworld here is how you find the manual on things. type
man ping
or
man ifconfig
to get the manuals of ping or ifconfig. The manual contains ALOT more information than the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ping` is part of [`iputils`](https://github.com/iputils/iputils) package. To check its version run:

```
ping -V
```

Possible output showing version of the `iputils` package:

```
ping utility, iputils-s20180629
```

Comment: What does this number in the output represent?

Comment: @x89, it represents version of the `iputils` package, and therefore version of `ping`